# How to get nodes that have one label or another Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher queries that looks like this

```
MATCH (r:Child)
WHERE r.uuid IS NULL
OPTIONAL MATCH r-[re]-(n)
delete r, re

MATCH (r:Parent)
WHERE r.uuid IS NULL
OPTIONAL MATCH r-[re]-(n)
delete r, re
```

Great but now I would like to combine these. Is there anyway I could do something like this...

```
MATCH (r:Parent||Child)
...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use or on the where clause

```
Match (r)
WHERE (r:Parent OR r:Child) and r.uuid IS NULL
```

Comment: But it will be an expensive query, I'd rather do a UNION